# Plot csv data on a map

Tags: qgis, csv, maps, representation

My boundaries shape file has the following attributes; CODE, PROVINCE, AREA, SHAPE_LENG and SHAPE_AREA (note that there are no geo- coordinates). My data on the csv file has the following fields; PROVINCE, MALE, FEMALE. What l need is to have proportional symbol like a circle representing the males and females for each of the provinces on the map. How can l accomplish this???

Comment: Did you try this http://docs.qgis.org/html/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_diagram_overlay.html

Comment: Yes l did but it didn't work out.

Comment: Could you please upload the screenshot contains shape file + its attributes..thanks..bcoz I am able to create pie-chart at my end.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue you're having is getting the coordinates, you can either calculate the centroids (in QGIS, it's Vector > Geometry Tools > Polygon Centroids), run the provinces through a [geocoder](http://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/), or if there are not too many, just go one-by-one and Google '[Province Name] coordinates.'

Once you get the coordinates, you can load the points into QGIS and import whatever markers you want to use.